# Function which is integrable on [a,b] but the lower and upper Darboux sums converges to different numbers for a given sequence of partitions of [a,b]

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

> Suppose ${P_n}$ is a sequence of partitions of $[a,b]$, each of which is refined by its successor (i.e., $\forall n \in \mathbb N, P_n \subseteq P_{n+1} $). Show that for any bounded $f :[a,b]\to \mathbb R$, integrability of $f$ on $[a,b]$ does not guarantee that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\underline{S}(f,P_n)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\overline{S}(f,P_n)$.

We can show it by counterexample. Take function $f(x)=x$ on $[0,2]$ and $P_n=\{0,\frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{2}{2^n},....,\frac{2^n}{2^n},2\}$. From this I get $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\underline{S}(f,P_n) = 3/2$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\overline{S}(f,P_n)= 5/2$. These two are not equal.

As $f(x)=x$ is a continuous function on $[0,2]$, so is integrable on $[0,2]$. I have studied that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and there exist a sequence $\{P_n\}$ of partitions of $[a,b]$ such that $\underline{S}(f,P_n)\to L$ and $\overline{S}(f,P_n)\to M$, then $L=M=\int_{a}^bf$. But why here we get a contradiction in the solution to the above question as we get a sequence of partition such that 
$\underline{S}(f,P_n)$ and $\overline{S}(f,P_n)$ converges but to different numbers? Why this happens?

Comment: I assume that the last point of $P_n$ should be 2, not 1?  In that case the partitions do not get arbitrarily fine.

Comment: Yes it is 2. I have edited it.

Comment: Well unless you have norm of $P_n$ tending to $0$ you can't guarantee that the limit of upper and lower sums are equal.

Comment: Does the norm of $P_n$ tending to 0 mean that the separation between two elements of $P_n$ tend to 0 as n tends to $\infty$?

Comment: Norm of a partition is the length of largest subinterval created by the partition. In symbols if $P=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ is a partition then its norm $||P||$ is defined to be $\max_{k=1}^{n}(x_k-x_{k-1})$.

Comment: So when norm tends to $0$ length of every subinterval tends to $0$. In your words separation between every two consecutive points of the partition tends to $0$.

Comment: In your counter-example the norm always remains $1$ (the length of last subinterval $[2^n/2^n,2]$).

Comment: Ok. The norm remains 1 of the given $P_n$. If I take $P_n = \{0,1/n,2/n,.......,2n/n\}$, then I get $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\underline{S}(f,P_n)=2=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\overline{S}(f,P_n)$. Because here norm of $P_n$ tend to 0.

Comment: Yes that's correct. No matter what sequence of partitions you take, if you can ensure that norm tends to $0$ then upper sums will converge to upper Darboux integral and lower sums will converge to lower Darboux integral. For Riemann integrable functions these two integrals are equal.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy criterion, $f$ is integrable at $[a,b]$ if and only if there exists a sequence $ (P_n) $ of partitions of $[a,b]$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n))=0$$

The sequence you chosen does not necessarily satisfy that.

Comment: Yes, as in that partition the distance between the $2^n/2^n$ and 2 remains same as n increases.

Comment: There exist a partition P_n doesn't mean this partition is yours.